# (Plugin: Wordpress NextGen Gallery) How to show the gallery description in nextgen gallery view?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, nextgen-gallery, galleryview

I am trying to tweak NextGen Gallery plugin, and in particular the file nextgen-gallery/view/gallery.php to achieve displaying the gallery description, when I view the gallery.

So, in this file, I have added the following lines:

```
    ....
    <?php if (!defined ('ABSPATH')) die ('No direct access allowed'); ?>
    <?php if (!empty ($gallery)) : ?>

    <?php /** Lots of stuff added here by Mpampirina  **/ ?>
    <p> You are here: <a class="Link" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?></a> &gt;
        <?php $album = nggdb::find_album( get_query_var('album') ); ?> 
        <?php echo $album->name ?> &gt; <?php echo $gallery->title ?>
    </p>

    <div class="ngg-description">
        <p>Here I want to add the gallery description text. So I try with: 
            <?php echo $gallery->gallerydesc ?> . Also I try with: 
            <?php echo $gallery->galdesc ?> . 
            I get no description, whatsoever...
        </p> 
    </div>
    <?php /** End of stuff added by Mpampirina **/ ?>
     
    <div class="ngg-galleryoverview" id="<?php echo $gallery->anchor ?>">
    ...
```

And here is the output:
[image: gallery view without description]

The gallery description of course is not empty. There is text added, in the 'Manage Gallery" menu:
[image: description text in admin pages]

So, is there anybody who can see what I am doing wrong, or maybe point me to another question page that I might have missed? It would be very helpful! :-)
Thank you in advance

Comment: I found the solution, by pure luck and it was just before my eyes. `<?php echo $gallery->description ?>`. Simple as that :S

Answer (score 2):

I just dealt with the same problem...

```
$gallery->description
```

Comment: Should have read more in depth... Didn't see that you already found the solution... Sorry about that!